# How to get the attributes of the selected products

Tags: product-attribute

I'm new to Magento. Could you please spare few minutes to help me out?

I have added a new button in Catalog->Manage Products Grid.

When i select few products in the Product List and click my new button, i need to get all the attributes (Price, Product ID, SKU, status, etc,..) for the selected (check box selected) products.

And how to iterate through the list ?
Could you please help me with the above.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could go with getting all `attributesetids` for all your products.
After that, use this to get all distinct attributes for those attribute sets.

```
$productIds = $this->getRequest()->getParam('product_ids'); // do not know yet, guessing

// Assuming that $productIds is a array containing productIds

$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');

$select = $collection->getSelect();
$connection = $collection->getConnection();

$select->reset(Zend_Db_Select::COLUMN)
    ->distinct()
    ->columns('attribute_set_id')
    ->where('entity_id', array('in' => $productId));

$attributeSetIds = $connection->fetchAll($select);

$attributes = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_collection')
    ->setAttributeSetsFilter($attributeSetIds);

foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
    var_dump($attribute->getFrontendLabel());
}
```